# How do I run a javascript project in SpringSource Tool Suite / Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, springsource, tcserver

I am using STSS 3.1 (GGTS version). I have created a small JavaScript project in STS and would like to run it using the internal vFabric tc server. The server reports that it started correctly, and the home page (showing a bunch of help links related to the server) displayed correctly.

But I cannot see how to load my application .html file. When I type its path, I get a 404 error.

I couldn't find any docs in the STS help on how to do this; I am sure I am missing something simple, but what?

Comment: What is the URL that you are going to? And are you sure that the application's html files are being deployed to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to do it using STS 3.4.0.RELEASE:

1. Open the vFabric server properties, e.g. double click it in the Servers view
2. Go to the Modules tab
3. Click "Add External Web Module..."
4. For "Document Base", browse to the directory containing yourindex.html.
5. For "Path", enter whatever path you want, e.g. "/YourProject"
6. Uncheck "Auto reloading enabled"
7. Save the server properties
8. Start the server and browse to `localhost:8080/YourProject/yourindex.html`